# PHP check if debug build

Tags: php, regex, optimization

In phpinfo() there is a listing for "Debug Build". Is there a constant assigned to this anywhere or any way to efficiently grab this value without having to scan through phpinfo for it?

Currently in the process of optimising a large amount of checking code and this is the only piece left that requires a line by line scan of the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a list of defined constants via `get_defined_constants()`:

```
var_dump(get_defined_constants()['ZEND_DEBUG_BUILD']); // true/false
```